# How to post xml to api controller and reading contents

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api application. The requesting URL contains large xml data.

```
http://localhost:15178/api/access?<xml><data>result</data></xml>


[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
  {
    string requstedXml = String.Empty;
    var t = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(s =>
    {
        requstedXml = s.Result;
    });
    t.Wait();
```

The above code is always Null. How could I read the xml?

Answer (score 1):

You are not POSTing the XML to the API, you are performing a GET so Request.Content is empty.

You could get the XML from the query string perhaps, or set the parameter name in your URL and Get method.

```
http://localhost:15178/api/access?xml=<xml><data>result</data></xml>

public IHttpActionResult Get(string xml)
{
}
```

Sending large chunks of XML over the query string though doesn't really seem like a good way of doing it.